# Solving Laplace's equation within an infinite domain

Tags: harmonic-functions

I try to solve Laplace's equation $\Delta u=0$ in the half plane:
$${d^2u\over dx^2}+{d^2u\over dy^2}\:=\:0
\quad\text{where } -\infty<x<\infty \text{ and }y>0
$$
and the boundary condition
$$\left.u\right|_{y=0}\:=\:\frac{x^2-1}{(x^2+1)^2} = \frac 1{x^2+1} - \frac{2}{(x^2+1)^2}$$
We can separate variables $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ and get ${X''\over X} = -{Y''\over Y} = k$,
but what to do next?
These conditions will be enough or not, maybe I have to use polar coordinates and the Poisson integral?

Comment: Just use Poisson's integral formula for the upper half plane: http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/poissonintegralplane/PoissonIntegralTheorem.1.pdf

Comment: Now you can solve $X'' = kX$ and $Y'' = -kY$, which gives $X = Ae^{-\sqrt{k}x}+Be^{\sqrt{k}x}$ and $Y = C \cos(\sqrt{k}x) + D \sin(\sqrt{k}x)$. You can then determine $A,B,C,D$ from the other conditions.